# Converting Motorcycle From Traditional Distributor to CDI Ignition System

Tags: engine, motorcycle, ignition, cdi

I have a 1985 Honda CG125.  The ignition uses contact points,  I  plan to convert it to CDI.  Nowadays, it is difficult to buy contact points and is troublesome to maintain them.

What will I need to replace for the conversion, and are those parts available?

Answer (score 2):

I did a search for "cdi conversion kit motorcycle" and found these two videos on YouTube:

- [Easy Sportbike Ignition Points Conversion for $25...Fast and Cheap!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dx7KWWeL8qk)
- [How to make motorcycle electronic ignition for £5 ($8) from a chainsaw or strimmer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPXbsWEs5IA)

I also tried searching for "honda CG125 cdi ignition conversion kit" and found this:

- [CG Honda 125 Kit 150cc CDI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRhOiNcqpOw)

Comment: Can I just replace with CD125 ingnition coil and CG125 CDI and rectifier unit.?

Comment: It sure looks that way (with the caveat that I work mostly on diesels and have never worked on small engines).

Comment: Any idea how to fix those stuff, like single line drawing to refer to.